# Documentation on when python automatically creates array copies

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, view, copy

I am trying to find documentation on when python automatically makes copies of numpy arrays. This is in relation to array views.

If simple indexing is used, an assignment makes an array view. If advanced indexing is used, python makes a copy. I have found other times when python makes array copies, but have not been able to locate the documentation. Here is an example:

```
a = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.])
av = a.view()
print(a)
print(av)
a[0] = 100.0
print(av)
a = 0
print(av)
```

Variable *av* was a view to *a* until *a* changed sufficiently that it could no longer be a view. Where is this documented?

Comment: [This Numpy copies & views tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_copies_and_views.htm) is probably the best way to understand what is going on.

Comment: `av` is a `view` of the original `a`. `a=0` assigns a new object to the variable `a`.  That change has nothing to do with `numpy` view/copy issue.

Comment: Thank you. At one time, av was a view into variable a. When the new assignment is made, av is no longer a view. I am trying to find documentation on how python changes a view to something else, and what triggers that. It must be some sort of logic that keeps track of what av is a view to. Then, when that thing changes, it changes av. Interesting logic I am trying to learn about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [118]: a = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.]) 
     ...: av = a.view()                                                                                         
In [119]: a                                                                                                     
Out[119]: array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
In [120]: av                                                                                                    
Out[120]: array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
```

An array is an object with attributes like `dtype` and `shape`, plus a pointer to a databuffer (`base`).  We can get a summary of these attributes with:

```
In [121]: a.__array_interface__                                                                                 
Out[121]: 
{'data': (69293648, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (5,),
 'version': 3}
```

`av` is a new array object, but it has the same attributes, including the `data`:

```
In [122]: av.__array_interface__                                                                                
Out[122]: 
{'data': (69293648, False),       # same value as for a
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (5,),
 'version': 3}
```

compare that with a `copy`:

```
In [123]: bv = a.copy()                                                                                         
In [124]: bv.__array_interface__                                                                                
Out[124]: 
{'data': (77843920, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (5,),
 'version': 3}
```

Other views may have different values - slices have different shape and strides etc.  But the databuffer will be the same (the actual number shown in `__array_interface__['data']` might be a little different, pointing to a different element in the buffer.

Change an element of `a`, and we see that change in `av` as well - because of the shared data buffer:

```
In [125]: a[0] =12                                                                                              
In [126]: av[0]                                                                                                 
Out[126]: 12.0
In [127]: bv[0]                                                                                                 
Out[127]: 1.0
```

When you assign something else to `a`, `av` does not change.

```
In [128]: a = 10                                                                                                
In [129]: a.__array_interface__                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-3b348559b028> in <module>
----> 1 a.__array_interface__

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'
In [130]: av.__array_interface__                                                                                
Out[130]: 
{'data': (69293648, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (5,),
 'version': 3}
```

`a` is an integer, not an array.  The data buffer that was originally created for `a` still exists, serving as the base for `av`.  Otherwise the original `a` object is gone.

I need to qualify that last statement - due to the output buffering of `ipython`, that array object still exists:

```
In [131]: Out[119].__array_interface__                                                                          
Out[131]: 
{'data': (69293648, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (5,),
 'version': 3}

In [132]: Out[119][0]                                                                                           
Out[132]: 12.0
```

I maybe should have displayed the `id(a)` etc, to clarify

```
In [133]: id(av)                                                                                                
Out[133]: 139992523130800
In [134]: id(Out[119])                                                                                          
Out[134]: 139992142353312
```

changes to `av` appear in `Out[119]`, but not in `a` - because `a` is an entirely different object.

```
In [144]: av[1] = 100                                                                                           
In [145]: Out[119]                                                                                              
Out[145]: array([ 12., 100.,   3.,   4.,   5.])
In [146]: a                                                                                                     
Out[146]: 10
```

So at some level you need to understand the nature of Python variables and objects.  For example that `b=a` just creates another name or reference to the same object, not a copy.  `b = a.copy()` makes a copy, but the details of that copy depend on the object class.  `numpy` adds a variation on `copy`, the `view`, that lets it save time and memory.  But you have to know something about its data storage mechanism to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

From NumPy docs at [Advanced Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

> Advanced indexing is triggered when the selection object, obj, is a non-tuple sequence object, an ndarray (of data type integer or bool), or a tuple with at least one sequence object or ndarray (of data type integer or bool). There are two types of advanced indexing: integer and Boolean.
>
> **Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a view).**

You can use the attribute [base](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.base.html) to check if a ndarray is a copy or a view of another.

```
a = np.arange(0, 10)

b = a.view()
print(b.base is a) # True

c, d = a[2:], a[::2]
print(c.base is a and d.base is a) # True

b = a.copy()
print(b.base is a) # False

b = a[a >= 5]
print(b.base is a) # False
```

EDIT:
I found interesting that you can create a view 'b' to an array 'a' and then change the original array memory address (using the method resize). The view 'base' attribute of a still points to b, but changes on b are not reflected on a:

```py
a = np.arange(0, 10)
b = a.view()
print(np.shares_memory(a, b)) # True
print(b.base is a) # True

a.resize(50, refcheck=False)
print(np.shares_memory(a, b)) # False
print(b.base is a) # True

b[0] = 20
print(a[0] == b[0]) # False
```

Another trick you can do is change manually the 'data' attribute of a view. If you do that, the 'base' attribute changes:

```py
a, b = np.arange(0, 10), np.arange(10, 20)
c = a.view()
print(c.base is a) # True

c.data = b.data
print(c.base is a) # False
print(c.base is b) # False
print(c[0]) # 10
print(c.base) # 'Memory at ....'
print(c.base == c.data == b.data) # True
```

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of the documentation regarding indexing. I have not found documentation on how python dynamically changes something from a view to a non-view. av was a view. Then it becomes not a view. This can be verified using base as you've suggested. However, it's not related to slicing.